# Hyper-V VHD running out of disk space

Tags: hyper-v

I have a HyperV VM with a dynamically expanding VHD.

Current File size = 290GB

Max disk size = 300GB

The VM itself (Windows 2008R2) is showing as 128GB free of the 300GB drive.

What is using up the space in the VHD?

Do I just need to turn off the VM and compact the VHD?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`What is using up the space in the VHD?` - It could be anything. Have you recently cleaned up system files in the guest OS? Have you recently deleted a large amount of data in the guest OS?

`Do I just need to turn off the VM and compact the VHD?` - Yes.

Comment: The VM is a TFS server. I'm not aware of any clean-up activity...but some Devs to have access...